# How do I delete from a table that holds a Foreign Key, knowing the referenced table's Primary Key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-delete

I have a 1:Many relationship between Order:Stops.

Order.OrderId is the primary key.
Order.FileNumber is a column I want to delete Stops by.

Stop.OrderId is the foreign key, referencing an Order's primary key. There can be many Stops to one Order. Stop.StopId is the Stop's primary key.

Deleting Orders first, SQL comes up with an error on the foreign key constraint. Deleting Stops first, followed by deleting their corresponding Orders, does *not* cause any errors.

What would the SQL statement look like if I wanted to delete Stops where I know the Order.FileNumber?

I'm assuming something like:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Stop] Stop LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Order] Ord
WHERE Ord.DriverNo = 123 AND Ord.FileNo = 456789 
AND Ord.OrderId = Stop.OrderId

GO
```

but nothing is working. We are working with SQL Server 2012.

Comment: you can't delete a record in a parent table until all child records are gone, unless you have a cascade delete set up.  and a delete can remove records from a single table only. you can't do multi-table deletes.

Comment: I'm actually deleting the children first, not the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below using a `INNER JOIN`

```
DELETE S 
FROM [dbo].[Stop] S 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order] Ord
ON Ord.OrderId = S.OrderId
WHERE Ord.DriverNo = 123 
AND Ord.FileNo = 456789
```

You can as well make it a cascading delete by using `ON DELETE CASCADE` while defining the Foreign Key (OR) with a `ALTER TABLE ...` statement which will make sure that, deleting a parent record the related record in child table also gets deleted (OR) the delete operation will be cascaded.

Comment: Thank you very much Rahul, this is exactly what I needed! I'm in the process of learning to make this a cascading delete.